# Force one session per user Golang and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, session, go

I'm building a web application using Go, and it will be just a bunch of ReST services.
I plan to use AngularJS as the front end, and it will make service calls to the Go application.

I plan to deploy to Google App Engine, and use it's user authentication service.
Is it possible to then limit a user's session to one at a time, so that a user may not share their login with someone else, and then have that that login logged in multiple times concurrently?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible.  Anything is possible.  Please update your question to reflect something more concrete -- which part of the implementation of such a mechanism is giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm looking for a direction to get going in implementing it. How about storing a session id in the DB and then checking if a session id exists when the login function is clicked. I can get rid of the session id on logout, but how would I get rid of the session id if the browser is closed?

Comment: So, the question would be "How do I expire a user's session when they close the browser?" (use a session cookie)